# Easily accessible snow in Nepal

Tags: nepal, snow

I'm planning to go to Nepal around November, December. Can I know of some places where we can stay and experience considerable snow, but that place has to be a village or town with regular transport to Kathmandu or another major city. From my search so far, it seems that you can only find snow high up in the mountains and this takes days of trekking, but I want a place that is not that desolate. Do any of you know of such a town or village or place in Nepal?

I was thinking about Kodari, but it doesn't seem to have much snow.

Please don't tell me to go to North India; I really do want to go to Nepal.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Associated question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61395/snow-access-in-north-india-in-the-winter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I visited the Annapurna range in Novemember/December. There was plenty of snow on the high mountains, it looked very picturesque. If you want to reach the snow line you will have to reach an altitude of at least 4000 metres. Do not attempt this without acclimatising first.

You should be able to get a bus from Kathmandu to Besisahar. From there you should be able to get an onward bus heading to Manang (3500 metres). There is only one road. I say road, its more of a dirt track. It will not be a comfortable ride. Don't go straight to Manang, give yourselves time to acclimatise first. I recommend that you stop at Chame and Pisang on the way to Manang.

Also, bring warm clothing, its gets very cold at night-time.

Answer (score 11):

I grew up in Nepal and I suggest you go to places like Dhulikhel, Banepa, Bandipur and Pokhara. These places are 3-4 hours of drive from Kathmandu and you can easily get into a bus from Kalanki, Kathmandu.

The top places for snow would be Phulchowki. I have personally trekked there and I think you can get a bus to take you there as well. The view from the top of Phulchowki is spectacular and there is a little army base too. You can visit the camp (people are super nice) and hopefully experience some snow as well. If you have more time, places like Mustang and Jomsom are heavenly.

People will try to over-charge you for everything since you are a tourist, but always do bargain, just raise your voice and tell them to bugger off. Most of the taxi drivers are cheaters and they would cheat you on the fare as well. Just be aware :)

I have lived in Nepal for 18 years and the first time I saw snow was when I moved to US. It's kinda hard to experience snow in Nepal unless you pack your bags and are ready for some adventure (mostly by hiking/trekking)

Answer (score 5):

Well visiting the snowy place and play with the lighting snow is everyone's dream. Some of the easily accessible Snowy place in Nepal on Winter Season are:

1. Tistung, Palung, Daman
   You can easily reach there with almost  hours of ride from athmandu
2. Kalinchok
   Kalinchok can be reached with almost 9 hours of ride from Kathmandu
3. [Ghorepani](https://www.mountfacenepal.com/destination/nepal/annapurna-region/ghorepani-poonhill-trekking)
   Ghorepani can be reached with 2 days of the hike from Pokhara
4. Gosainkunda
   Gosainkunda can be reached with 2 days of a hike from Dhunche which is a day ride away from Kathmandu
5. Phulchoki
   Phulchoki is just 2 hours or maybe 3 hours of drive from the Kathmandu Valley. On the way you will explore almost the aerial view of Kathmandu valley

Answer (score 2):

If you go upwards at elevation more than 4000 meters during december to feburuary there is 75% chance you will catch snow ..but remember the places above 4000m. requires trekking. Last winter i went to four places of Nepal and there were snowfall in all those places .. Dolpa, Gosaikunda, Kalinchowk, Annapurna Base Camp... well you can also find snow anywhere Nepal above 4000m but the problem is not in every places snow will remain , most places sun melts all the snow after 2-3 days of snowfall, well not in Abc though it takes at least 1-2 week for snow to vanish. The nearest to place to catch snow is Kalinchowk (3700m) though, takes 6 hours by bus and there is another place near kalinchowk called sailung that also recieves pretty good snowfall...

Answer (score 1):

TBH, I don't think there will be any such place. AFAI have heard, snow is only found high mountains, and it takes some trekking to get there. Nepal is NOT your regular winter vacation.