# Snow Access in North India in the winter

Tags: india, backpacking, new-delhi, snow, north-india

If I travel to northern India in winter (around November/December), where will I be able to experience considerable snow. I want a less touristy place (not like Manali) within 12-16 hours reach of new Delhi by public transport. If there is none, what would be my best bet in India except for Jammu & Kashmir?

Comment: Associated question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61081/easily-accesible-snow-in-nepal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most of North India doesn't see snow, and the winter temperatures almost never reach close to freezing.

The places that see snow are `J&K`, `Himachal Pradesh` and some parts of `Uttarakhand`. [This article](http://www.weareholidays.com/articles/top-10-winter-destinations-snow-lovers-india/) has some places that you can visit.
Most of these places however don't have good public transport connectivity from `Delhi`.

The other place where it snows is in the `North East` beyond Sikkim, but that's a fair distance away from `Delhi`.

I'd really recommend that you go the `Laddhak` region in `J&K`, it is much safer than places in `Kashmir`, it is definitely a once in a lifetime experience. You'll find snow, rivers, old buddhist monasteries and a landscape that's literally out of this world.

To summarize, there aren't all that many Non Touristy places reasonably close to Delhi with good public transport connectivity. You'll have to take the road less taken.

Comment: How much time does it take to Ladakh from ND? What are my transit options?

Comment: You have options to hire a vehicle from Manali or Srinagar if you want to go by road. Otherwise you could fly to Leh and hire a vehicle to explore there.
Road options would take a few days, flight is 2 and 1/2 hours or so.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to recommend **Nainital** and **Pithoragarh** in Uttarakhand and **Dalhousie** in Himachal Pradesh. These places are less touristy than Shimla and Manali. It usually snow during December and January, however it often depends on one's luck. These places are also easily accessible by bus from New Delhi.